# Creating a database on a shared directory through the server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am creating a program to create a database "setup" on a existing sql server on the company server.

```
     strcreate = "CREATE DATABASE " & "Setup ON" & _
           "(NAME = " & "Setup" & "_DATA, " & _
           " FILENAME = 'C:\data\DATA\Setup.MDF', " & _
           " SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = 200MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)"
```

Easy enough to create but how would I create it if it wasn't on the c drive and i dont know the names of the drives? Could i manipulate a folder browser dialog to search through the server drives or?

If more code is needed just ask.

also if i was creating the database on a shared directory on the company server yet the sql server was local the path is \servername\directory\setup.mdf. why wouldnt this work with the server does it not like refering to itself like that or ?

Comment: Do you want the end user to select the file location?  Or do you want to "decide" in your code?

Comment: end user should be able to select. ultimately this is part of a setup configuration before it being help in a configuration file preventing users from changing it. I am assuming the person setting this up has admin rights to the server.

Comment: Stored proc `xp_fixeddrives` will show you the fixed drives on the SQL Server host, with remaining free space (in MB) on each drive.

Comment: thanks this helps. half of learning a new language is finding out such features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored proc `xp_fixeddrives` will show you the fixed drives on the SQL Server host, with remaining free space (in MB) on each drive.